# How much time does it take for the DHS TRIP letter to arrive to India? Is there any way to track it?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

I had applied for DHS TRIP and they closed the case and sent me a letter but it hasn't reached me. It has now been 10 days. I actually have two addresses and dont remember which one i had put in while filling the form. Can I track it?

Comment: For an ordinary letter, estimate 2-3 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

If they sent it with a courier service (Federal express, ...) they should have given you a tracking number, then you can check on their web site.

If they sent it by regular mail, then it is hard to track, and can take a long time, especially in India.

I'd wait for another week, and check both addresses if you can; after that, you could contact the DHS and inquire about it.

Comment: I've already inquired with DHS but they aren't replying to my emails. How long do you think it'll take if sent by regular mail. They haven't given me a tracking number or anything

Comment: They aren't replying to my mails, what can I do in this case?